# Any issues working with TFS 2010 and where company has vs2008 and office 2003

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I really wanted to know if people have found **any compatibility issues working with TFS 2010 and projects in vs2008** in terms of source control, daily build, continuous integration, work item tracking, etc. I understand that we can connect to TFS 2010 from VS2008.

We are planning to onboard to TFS, but really need to make a choice between TFS 2008 or TFS 2010. We want to onboard to TFS 2010 due to its compelling features.
But we are worried about the following:
1) All our projects are still in vs 2008
2) We do not want upgrade to vs 2010 now due to price issues.
3) TFS 2010 is new
4) All clients have Office 2003 and upgrading to office 2007 will be huge cost

Will it be good to onboard to TFS 2010 when our projects are still in vs2008 and ms office is 2003 ? We do not want to run into compatibility issues later working with tfs 2010.

Comment: Just a quick comment:  We just upgraded to VS 2010 and it was a painless operation.  The conversion process from 2008 to 2010 projects happened without a problem.

Comment: That is true but we just upgraded to 2008 and we do not have budget to upgrade again this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a mix of VS 2008 and VS 2010 users. Support is using both VS 2008 against VSS and TFS 2010 and VS 2010 against TFS 2010. Development is using VS 2010 against TFS 2010. The Office versions range from me and others using 2002, some using 2003 and a few using 2007.

We have not run into any issues that stop us from doing our jobs.

I would recommend using TFS 2010. You should have no issues with using VS 2008 and Office 2003. TFS 2010 is leaps and bounds above 2008 and is much easier to install and configure.

Answer (score 0):

We have had numerous problems using TFS 2010 to build VS 2008 projects.  Building 2008 projects from TFS 2010 does not pose any real problems.  One problem we have is that code analysis warnings found in 2008 projects were not reported in TFS 2010 build reports.  Another problem, that will be fixed by Microsoft in the future, is that TFS 2010 does not report test results for projects with unit tests where some unit tests fail.  We've also had difficulties getting changesets correctly associated with builds; TFS seems to associate random changesets at times with our builds.